# Java Reading zip file

Tags: java, filesystems, zip

I'm trying to read the content of a ZIP file. 
When creating the FileSystem, I get a **FileSystemAlreadyExistsException** since the affected zip file already exists.
Even when I'm specifying {"create", "false"} when creating the FileSystem

The code (adapted from http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html):

```
private static FileSystem createZipFileSystem(String zipFilename,
                                          boolean create)
                                          throws IOException {
    // convert the filename to a URI
    final Path path = Paths.get(zipFilename);
    final URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + path.toUri().getPath());

    final Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    String value="false";

    if (create) {
        value="true";            
    }        
    env.put("create", value);

    return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
}
```

the call:

```
 FileSystem zipFileSystem = createZipFileSystem(zipFilename, false);
```

Comment: `FileSystemAlreadyExistsException` does not mean "zip file already exists". It means "zip file already loaded as a file system". Re-use the created `FileSystem`, e.g. behind a singleton class or as a shared resource, or if you're sure that this zip file won't be opened in multiple threads, close your `FileSystem` instances once you're done with them.

Comment: Excellent!. The following code substituting the above return sentence did the work:  if (FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri).isOpen()){
            return FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);
        }
        return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);

Comment: However I still don't quite understand why. Debugging the application it is absolutely clear to me that the error arose the first  time I was creating the filesystem object.....Anyway, Many thanks indeed for your help